# Show value when CASE expression does not return rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

This code returns a fixed column `198` and then another one with a `CASE`. This `CASE` may return 0 rows (because there's also 0 row with `TRL_ORIGQTY` in the database, so it's not even evaluated)

If there are rows, the result is (tested with other organizations):

```
ORG     SumTotal
198      98.51
```

If there are no rows in the database, the result shows nothing, but it should be:

```
ORG     SumTotal
198      NULL
```

or whatever:

```
ORG     SumTotal
198      00001
```

This is the full code:

```
declare @startdate varchar(30);
declare @enddate varchar(30);
declare @count int;    

set @startdate = '2017-12-01'
set @enddate = '2018-01-01'    

select @count = COUNT(*)
from R5TRANSLINES
where TRL_TYPE = 'STTK' 
  and TRL_TRANS in (select TRA_CODE from R5TRANSACTIONS 
                    where TRA_FROMCODE in ('198') 
                      and TRA_STATUS in ('A') 
                      and TRA_DATE between @startdate and @enddate)

select distinct 
    '198' as 'ORG',
    (SUM(CASE
            WHEN (TRL_ORIGQTY = 0 AND TRL_ORIGQTY > 0) THEN 0
            WHEN ((TRL_ORIGQTY - TRL_QTY) = 0 AND TRL_ORIGQTY = 0) THEN 100
            WHEN ((TRL_ORIGQTY - TRL_QTY) > TRL_ORIGQTY) THEN ((TRL_ORIGQTY / (TRL_ORIGQTY - TRL_QTY)) * 100)
            ELSE (((TRL_ORIGQTY - TRL_QTY) / TRL_ORIGQTY) * 100)
         END) OVER ()/@count) AS 'SumTotal'
from 
    R5TRANSLINES
where 
    TRL_TYPE = 'STTK' 
    and TRL_TRANS in (select TRA_CODE from R5TRANSACTIONS 
                      where TRA_FROMCODE in ('198') 
                        and TRA_STATUS in ('A')  
                        and TRA_DATE between @startdate and @enddate)
```

Tried with `ISNULL`, or `NOT EXISTS`, or even with another `CASE = NULL`, but none of them work... no rows returned.

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
select distinct
    'ESREQ1' as 'ORG',
    CASE COUNT(*) 
       WHEN 0 THEN 0
       ELSE (SUM(CASE
                    WHEN (TRL_ORIGQTY = 0 AND TRL_ORIGQTY > 0) THEN 0
                    WHEN ((TRL_ORIGQTY - TRL_QTY) = 0 AND TRL_ORIGQTY = 0) THEN 100
                    WHEN ((TRL_ORIGQTY - TRL_QTY) > TRL_ORIGQTY) THEN ((TRL_ORIGQTY / (TRL_ORIGQTY - TRL_QTY)) * 100)
                    ELSE (((TRL_ORIGQTY - TRL_QTY) / TRL_ORIGQTY) * 100)
                 END) OVER ()/@count) 
    END AS 'SumTotal'
from 
    R5TRANSLINES
where 
    TRL_TYPE = 'STTK' 
    and TRL_TRANS in (select TRA_CODE from R5TRANSACTIONS 
                      where UPPER(TRA_DESC) like '%AUDITESREQ1%' 
                        and TRA_FROMCODE in ('138-05') 
                        and TRA_STATUS in ('A') 
                        and TRA_DATE between @startdate and @enddate)
group by 
    TRL_ORIGQTY, TRL_QTY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have 0 rows returning is that a `SUM` of 0 rows will return no rows (thus no dataset). The only exception to this is when using `COUNT`; which returns a 0 when there are no rows.

You could, therefore, use a further `CASE` expression before hand with a `COUNT(*)`, and then put the `SUM` in the `ELSE`.

```
SELECT '198' AS ORG, --DISTINCT achieves nothing here, so I have removed it.
       CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN 0
                     ELSE ... --your SUM
       END AS SumTotal
FROM R5TRANSLINES ...
```

Also, please think about using White Space when writing SQL. Your Code is very difficult to read to the complete lack of indentation. It makes your life easier, and anyone else that needs to read your statements. (this is why I haven't rewritten your query, as i'd spend more time formatting it than anything else).

Edit: Based on the OPs latest SQL:

```
SELECT 'ESREQ1' AS ORG,
       CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN 0
                     ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN (TRL_ORIGQTY = 0 AND TRL_ORIGQTY > 0) THEN 0
                                   WHEN ((TRL_ORIGQTY - TRL_QTY) = 0 AND TRL_ORIGQTY = 0) THEN 100
                                   WHEN ((TRL_ORIGQTY - TRL_QTY) > TRL_ORIGQTY) THEN ((TRL_ORIGQTY / (TRL_ORIGQTY - TRL_QTY)) * 100)
                                   ELSE (((TRL_ORIGQTY - TRL_QTY) / TRL_ORIGQTY) * 100)
                              END) / @count
       END AS SumTotal
FROM R5TRANSLINES
WHERE TRL_TYPE ='STTK'
  AND TRL_TRANS IN (SELECT TRA_CODE
                    FROM R5TRANSACTIONS
                    WHERE UPPER(TRA_DESC) LIKE '%AUDITESREQ1%'
                      AND TRA_FROMCODE IN ('138-05') 
                      AND TRA_STATUS = 'A'
                      AND TRA_DATE BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate);
```

Note that this is untested, as I don't have any sample data to run this against. If this still doesn't work, please provide some DDL and consumable Sample data, that we can run against.

Thanks.

Comment: After adding your code (and a needed group by) there's still 0 rows returned. See updated code.

Comment: Why did you add a `GROUP BY`? There was no need for one before.

Comment: It asks for a group by clausule after adding your code.
`Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Column 'R5TRANSLINES.TRL_ORIGQTY' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @Piston I've added a new version for you. There was no need to add a `GROUP BY`, nor was there for the `OVER()` clause (this explains why you had a `DISTINCT` too). I've removed all of these.